# IIS redirect root to subdirectory with SSL domain

Tags: iis

I'm trying to redirect from the **root** IIS Url to **root/myapp**, using the following URL Rewrite rule in IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect Root" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/test" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works when I use `https://localhost/`, however when I use `https://my-public-domain/` it doesn't redirect to `https://my-public-domain/myapp` as needed.

The Default Web Site has a HTTPS binding with an SSL certificate.

```
        <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <application path="/MyApp" applicationPool="MyAppAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Program Files\IIS\MyApp" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" sslFlags="0" />
            </bindings>
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging enabled="true" />
        </site>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Read FRT to see what happens.

Comment: It seems that the request didn't have any failed requests associated with it, it only failed to redirect as I expect it to from URL rewrite rule.

Comment: 1. Use the privacy mode of your web browser to test, because in other modes the browser can simply fool you by caching what it thinks to be right. 2. Make sure your site bindings are correct, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html or the requests go to another site and your rewrite rules might not trigger.